# Next 13 error node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/spec-extension/cookies/serialize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

My application on next throws errors when the serialize function is used

```
error - node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/spec-extension/cookies/serialize.js (40:0) @ parseCookieString
error - URI malformed
```

[image]

[image]

I tried almost everything, I can not understand where to look for the error. It seems to me that this is probably a Next 13 bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of node. Had the same issue and upgrading node to 20 fixed it.